# Referring to an object previously mentioned in the sentence

Tags: grammar

I wish to know, if the bellow sentence is grammatically correct and where I can find more information on forming such sentences

> Can you share with me the coordinates of the measuring station, who's
>   data you sent me last week?

**Context**: Last week a friend of mine sent me some data and asked me to analyse it. Now I wish to know the coordinates, but I'm not sure, if by using *who* in the sentence, I am referring to the *measuring station* in the correct manner (is it a *he*, a *she*, or an *it*).

Comment: There is an excellent answer by John Lawler in this [related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/368341/which-instead-of-whose-for-inanimate-objects).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the comma and use "whose":

> Can you share with me the coordinates of the measuring station whose data you sent me last week?

"Whose" is the possessive form of "who", while "who's" is a contraction of "who is".

Besides that, your sentence is both correct and idiomatic.

Comment: You already have a good answer to your question.  This is a little piece of advice about clarity.  First orient your reader by giving the context of the request; then make the request.  For example.  “Thank you for sending me the data last week.  Could you please send me the co-ordinates of the measuring station?  Something like that.